# Laravel database request

Tags: php, laravel

I have an original request that I made in the Navicat program:

```
SELECT
tt1.team AS team1,
tt2.team AS team2,
tt1.logo AS team1_logo,
tt2.logo AS team2_logo,
tt1.id AS team1_id,
tt2.id AS `team2_id,`,
tournaments_matches.`status`,
tournaments_matches.started_at,
tt1.x AS x1,
tt2.x AS x2,
tournaments_matches.live,
tournaments_matches.winner_id
FROM
tournaments_teams AS tt1
INNER JOIN tournaments_teams AS tt2 ON tt1.match_id = tt2.match_id AND tt1.id != tt2.id
INNER JOIN tournaments_matches ON tournaments_matches.match_id = tt2.match_id AND tournaments_matches.match_id = tt1.match_id
GROUP BY
tt1.match_id
```

I tried to remake this query in Laravel Query Builder, I got this:

```
    $opponents = DB::select('tt1.team as team1','tt2.team as team2','tt1.logo as team1_logo','tt2.logo as team2_logo','tt1.id as team1_id','tt2.id as team2_id,','tournaments_matches.status','tournaments_matches.started_at','tt1.x as x1','tt2.x as x2','tournaments_matches.live','tournaments_matches.winner_id')
    ->from('tournaments_teams as tt1')
    ->join('tournaments_teams as tt2', function($join) {
        $join->on('tt1.match_id', '=', 'tt2.match_id')
            ->on('tt1.id', '!=', 'tt2.id');
        })
    ->join('tournaments_matches', function($join) {
        $join->on('tournaments_matches.match_id', '=', 'tt2.match_id')
            ->on('tournaments_matches.match_id', '=', 'tt1.match_id');
        })
    ->groupBy('tt1.match_id')
    ->get();

    var_dump($opponents); exit;
```

`tournaments_teams` and `tournaments_matches` it's a different tables in the database.

But when i try to access page, `var_dump` say me error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in`. Where is the problem? How i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for selects: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#selects

I think your issue in selecting a table, try:

```php
$opponents = DB::table('tournaments_teams as tt1')
    ->select('tt1.team as team1','tt2.team as team2','tt1.logo as team1_logo','tt2.logo as team2_logo','tt1.id as team1_id','tt2.id as team2_id,','tournaments_matches.status','tournaments_matches.started_at','tt1.x as x1','tt2.x as x2','tournaments_matches.live','tournaments_matches.winner_id')
    ->join('tournaments_teams as tt2', function($join) {
        $join->on('tt1.match_id', '=', 'tt2.match_id')
            ->on('tt1.id', '!=', 'tt2.id');
    })
    ->join('tournaments_matches', function($join) {
        $join->on('tournaments_matches.match_id', '=', 'tt2.match_id')
            ->on('tournaments_matches.match_id', '=', 'tt1.match_id');
    })
    ->groupBy('tt1.match_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: whoops. it was my mistake, now all work, thank you! **UPD:** but now, when i remove `var_dump` i received error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` :(

Comment: Great, please consider marking this as the answer to your question.